# Can swift exit out of the root closure?

Tags: swift, closures

In Swift, if I'm inside of a closure, that is itself inside of another function, is there a way to exit out of the function itself?

Here's an example of what this might look like using closures from the GCDKit library.

```
func test() {
    GCDQueue.Default.async {
        print("Print me!")
        return //Is there a statement that does this?
    }.notify(.Main) {
        print("Never print me.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No there is not. Closures run in self-contained environments. For all you know, by the time that closure is executed, the thread on which `test()` was called is no longer executing the `test()` method.

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a simpler version that doesn't include any third-party libraries, extra queues, or other complexity. We'll just create a closure and immediately execute it.

```
func dothing(andPrint shouldPrint: Bool) {
    let closure = {
        guard shouldPrint else { return }
        print("I printed!")
    }

    closure()
    print("did it return?")
}

dothing(andPrint: false) // Prints "did it return?"
```

The `return` here exits the closure, not `dothing`. Since `closure` could be passed to some other function, or stored in a property and executed at some later time (possibly on a different queue as in your example), there's no way for the `return` to exit anything beyond itself. Consider if we were to refactor the creation of the closure into its own function:

```
func fetchClosure(andPrint shouldPrint: Bool) -> () -> Void {
    return {
        guard shouldPrint else { return }
        print("I printed!")
    }
}

func dothing(andPrint shouldPrint: Bool) {
    let closure = fetchClosure(andPrint: shouldPrint)

    closure()
    print("did it return?")
}

dothing(andPrint: false) // Prints "did it return?"
```

It shouldn't be surprising this has the same behavior (otherwise this wouldn't be a simple refactor). Now imagine how it would (or even could) work if `return` behaved any other way.

Your example is just a much more complicated version of the same thing. `return` exits the closure.